# Cocos2d-x Animation Error

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to convert an animation from `cocos2d` to `cocos2d-x` but to no avail. I'm not getting any obvious error message, only that it occurs on the second to last line.

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("swim_male.plist");
CCSpriteBatchNode *sceneSpriteBatchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::batchNodeWithFile("swim_male.png");

this->addChild(sceneSpriteBatchNode);

CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::animation();
animation->setDelayPerUnit(.05f);    
char* fn = new char;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    sprintf(fn, "character_Male00%02d.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* pFrame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(fn);
    animation->addSpriteFrame(pFrame);
}

CCSprite *spriteAnim = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrameName("character_Male0001.png");
spriteAnim->setPosition( ccp(100, 200) );
CCAnimate *animate = CCAnimate::actionWithAnimation(animation);
CCAction *act = CCRepeatForever::actionWithAction(animate);
spriteAnim->runAction(act);

sceneSpriteBatchNode->addChild(spriteAnim, 2);
```

Comment: what the text of the error message?

Comment: it means that one of variables is NULL. check in debugger, what variable is NULL and causes crash

Comment: There's something wrong with this line:

Comment: CCSpriteFrame* pFrame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(fn);

even though the variable fn gives correct values

Comment: if pFrame is NULL, then there is no such sprite frame in spriteframe cache. check console. there can be error message. I assume it will begin with "cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: "

Comment: No there isn't anything else.

Can someone just provide for me the code to play a simple animation in cocos2d-x? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: or alternatively give me a way to convert my char (fn) to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating a single character to sprintf into. sprintf is then writing the string into memory outside of that pointed to by fn because it it longer than 1 character.

Instead of

```
char* fn = new char;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    sprintf(fn, "character_Male00%02d.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* pFrame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(fn);
    animation->addSpriteFrame(pFrame);
}
```

do this

```
char fn[128];

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    sprintf(fn, "character_Male00%02d.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* pFrame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(fn);
    animation->addSpriteFrame(pFrame);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

using c++,

```
char* fn = new char --> bad;
char* fn = new char[128];

...

delete []fn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Right like this

```
CCSpriteBatchNode* spritebatch = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("horse.png");
CCSpriteFrameCache* cache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("horse.plist");

hero = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("horse_1.png");
addChild(spritebatch);
spritebatch->addChild(hero);

CCArray* animFrames = CCArray::createWithCapacity(16);
char str[100] = {0};
for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
{
    sprintf(str, "horse_%i.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = cache->spriteFrameByName( str );
    animFrames->addObject(frame);
}
CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, .1f);
animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true);
hero->runAction( CCRepeatForever::create( CCAnimate::create(animation) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

char* fn = new char; doesn't specify the allocated size to fn.

you should write like

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
     char* fn = new char[strlen("character_Male0002d.png")+sizeof(i)+1];
     sprintf(fn, "character_Male00%02d.png", i);
     CCSpriteFrame* pFrame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(fn);
        animation->addSpriteFrame(pFrame);
  delete fn;
  fn = NULL ;
  }
```